# JPA Criteria query Path.get left join is it possible

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, criteria-api

I have a question regarding JPA criteria.

Here is my JPA criteria query:

```
 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEm().getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<InventoryItemSumReport> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(InventoryItemSumReport.class);
 Root<InventoryItemDetail> from = query.from(InventoryItemDetail.class);    

 Join<InventoryItemDetail, InventoryItem> joinItem = from.join(InventoryItemDetail_.inventoryItem); 

 Predicate where = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(from.get(InventoryItemDetail_.effectiveDate), date);

 query.multiselect(joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.product),joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.facility),joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.customer));
 query.groupBy(joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.product),joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.facility),joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.customer));
 query.where(where); 

 TypedQuery<InventoryItemSumReport> createQuery = getEm().createQuery(query);       
 List<InventoryItemSumReport> resultList = createQuery.getResultList();
```

Here is the resulting query produced by the JPA provider:

```
    select
        inventoryi1_.PRODUCT_ID as col_0_0_,
        inventoryi1_.FACILITY_ID as col_1_0_,
        inventoryi1_.CUSTOMER_ID as col_2_0_ 
    from
        INVENTORY_ITEM_DETAIL inventoryi0_ 
    inner join
        INVENTORY_ITEM inventoryi1_ 
            on inventoryi0_.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=inventoryi1_.ID 
    inner join
        PRODUCT product2_ 
            on inventoryi1_.PRODUCT_ID=product2_.ID 
    inner join
        FACILITY facility3_ 
            on inventoryi1_.FACILITY_ID=facility3_.ID 
    inner join
        CUSTOMER customer4_ 
            on inventoryi1_.CUSTOMER_ID=customer4_.ID 
    where
        inventoryi0_.EFFECTIVE_DATE<= ? 
    group by
        inventoryi1_.PRODUCT_ID ,
        inventoryi1_.FACILITY_ID ,
        inventoryi1_.CUSTOMER_ID
```

But I would like the following query:

```
    select
        inventoryi1_.PRODUCT_ID as col_0_0_,
        inventoryi1_.FACILITY_ID as col_1_0_,
        inventoryi1_.CUSTOMER_ID as col_2_0_ 
    from
        INVENTORY_ITEM_DETAIL inventoryi0_ 
    inner join
        INVENTORY_ITEM inventoryi1_ 
            on inventoryi0_.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=inventoryi1_.ID 
    inner join
        PRODUCT product2_ 
            on inventoryi1_.PRODUCT_ID=product2_.ID 
    inner join
        FACILITY facility3_ 
            on inventoryi1_.FACILITY_ID=facility3_.ID 
    left join
        CUSTOMER customer4_ 
            on inventoryi1_.CUSTOMER_ID=customer4_.ID 
    where
        inventoryi0_.EFFECTIVE_DATE<= ?
    group by
        inventoryi1_.PRODUCT_ID ,
        inventoryi1_.FACILITY_ID ,
        inventoryi1_.CUSTOMER_ID
```

with a **left join CUSTOMER** to get also results where `Customers` are null.
`Customer`, `Product`, `Facility` are all entites, while `InventoryItemSumReport` is a Value  object or DTO.

```
public class InventoryItemSumReport implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private Product product;
   private Facility facility;
   private Customer customer;

   public InventoryItemSumReport(Product product, Facility facility, Customer customer) {
       super();
       this.product = product;
       this.facility = facility;
       this.customer = customer;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found as follows it works:

```
 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEm().getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<InventoryItemSumReport> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(InventoryItemSumReport.class);
 Root<InventoryItemDetail> from = query.from(InventoryItemDetail.class);    

 Join<InventoryItemDetail, InventoryItem> joinItem = from.join(InventoryItemDetail_.inventoryItem); 

 Predicate where = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(from.get(InventoryItemDetail_.effectiveDate), date);

 Join<InventoryItem, Customer> joinCustomer = joinItem.join(InventoryItem_.customer, JoinType.LEFT);
 query.multiselect(joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.product),joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.facility),joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.customer));
 query.groupBy(joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.product),joinItem.get(InventoryItem_.facility),joinCustomer);
 query.where(where); 

 TypedQuery<InventoryItemSumReport> createQuery = getEm().createQuery(query);       
 List<InventoryItemSumReport> resultList = createQuery.getResultList();
```