# JPA Criteria API: LEFT JOIN for optional relationships

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api, metamodel

I'm using the Criteria API basically the first time. It's about abstracting queries for a generic builder:

```
public TypedQuery<T> newQuery( Manager<?,T> manager )
{
    CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    Class<T> genericClass = ( Class<T> ) ( ( ParameterizedType ) manager.getClass().getGenericSuperclass() ).getActualTypeArguments()[1];

    CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery( genericClass );
    Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from( genericClass );

    ...
}
```

The call `criteriaQuery.from( genericClass );` generates SQL `INNER JOIN` for all relationships found on the entity by default. This is a problem, because every relationship being null (DB `NULL` or a DB that doesn't use foreign keys and has an invalid reference) those entities will be missing in the result list, effectively producing wrong search results.

An example can be found here: [JPA Criteria query Path.get left join is it possibile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10145074/396732)

What I'd like to happen for queries instantiated by this class/method is that all relationships on the entity, here `genericClass`, that are mapped as `optional = true`

```
@ManyToOne( FetchType.EAGER, optional = true )
@JoinColumn( name = "CLOSE_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID" )
private User              closer;
```

to generate an SQL `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

**Question**:

*Is there standard JPQ way to get this done? If so, how?*

PS: there's generally no way to know the concrete type beforehand, so the only way I might be able to achieve what I need is to use the metamodel of some sort and generate the joins manually (which I'd like to avoid).

---

We are using EclipseLink 2.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.from(class) does not use an INNER join for all relationships, it only queries the class.

A relationship will only be queried if you use the join() or fetch() API, to use an outer join use join() with a JoinType.LEFT.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Join

I'm not sure why you are seeing joins if you are not calling join().  Some JPA providers automatically join fetch all EAGER relationships, this may be what you are seeing.  I have always though this odd, perhaps your JPA provider has a away to be configured not to do this, or you can make the relationships LAZY.

Comment: IIRC the problem was that we were using left join syntax for the from clauses, but were using standard joins for the order bys, which seemed to overshadow the previous left joins.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue...
After investigation the conclusion is That you hâve to handle this with left join in your jpql
See that:
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/path#Navigation_through_a_NULL_value_