# Create varargs @Query for same database column

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement a simple text search. I would like to allow a user to type any number of words, and check all of those words against the title of an article. A result would be returned if the title matched all of the words in the search (in any order).

Some example database queries would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE
    lower(title) like lower(concat('%', '<term1>', '%'));

SELECT * FROM Article WHERE
   lower(title) like lower(concat('%', '<term1>', '%'))
   AND lower(title) like lower(concat('%', '<term2>', '%'));

SELECT * FROM Article WHERE
   lower(title) like lower(concat('%', '<term1>', '%'))
   AND lower(title) like lower(concat('%', '<term2>', '%'));
   AND lower(title) like lower(concat('%', '<term3>', '%'));
```

Notice how the `title` column is searched in each case, and will be compared with either 1, 2, or 3 (or more) terms.

**Can I create a single JPQL query to do this?**

Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE lower(a.title) in %:terms%")
Iterable<Article> findAllContainingTitle(String... terms)
```

It appears Java's varargs work, but more in a sense of specific values within a set.

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938905/sql-query-to-match-one-of-multiple-strings), and [this link](https://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#LIKE_to_list_of_patterns) I learned how to do this directly in a Postgres query:

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE ~~* ALL(ARRAY['%term1%', '%term2%', '%term3%']);
```

The challenge now has been to try and convert this to a Spring Data JPA query.

Note: the `~~*` can also be exchanged with `ILIKE` (case insensitive `LIKE` statement).

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer my question, but it at least provides a workaround, should anyone else need something similar. Part of the requirement was to also use `JOIN FETCH` to pull back all data in a single query, and not run into the N+1 performance problem.

The workaround is to use `CriteriaBuilder` and `CriteriaQuery` to generate the query dynamically. I feel this creates a less readable query, but it certainly is better than nothing.

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

...

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()
CriteriaQuery<Content> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Article.class);

Root<Article> rootArticle = crirteriaQuery.from(Article.class);

// Provide any number of joins here
rootArticle.fetch("author", JoinType.INNER);

// This is where we dynamically add all of the 'like' statements
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
// Assume that 'searchQuery' is plain text from the user, that will be split on spaces to get individual search terms.
for (String searchTerm : searchQuery.split(" ")) {
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(
        criteriaBuilder.lower(rootArticle.get("title")),
        "%"+searchTerm.toLowerCase()+"%"));
}
criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

TypedQuery<Article> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Article> articles = query.getResultList();
```

Special thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593940/jpa-criteria-api-left-join-for-optional-relationships) which linked to [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Join) which explained how to add the `JOIN` statements to a `CriteriaQuery`.